# Can the gradient be expressed with contravariant components?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

I read that the gradient is an example of a quantity that transforms covariantly since in the below expression for the gradient
$$\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x'^i}$$ appears instead of $$\frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x^j}$$
This amounts to the use of the inverse matrix that would be used to express components in a contravariant context
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'^i}=\sum_j \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x'^i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}$$

I also read that

> Specifically, every vector has both contravariant and covariant
>   components that transform in predictable ways.

So does this mean it is meaningful to express the gradient in contravariant components with covariant basis vectors? If so is that useful at all, and if not why? And how does one derive the transformation rules in that context?

Comment: what is a covariant basis for you?

Comment: Covariant basis vectors are the same as dual basis are they not?

Comment: is it clear for you that each vector space $V$ has its dual $V^*$ and is different from $V$?

Comment: Isn't $V^*$ isomorphic to $V$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$? And if $V^*$ should be kept separate from $V$ then what does "every vector has both contravariant and covariant components that transform in predictable ways" mean if the gradient can't be expressed in basis vectors in $V$ and must be expressed in components with basis vectors in $V^*$.

Comment: Isomorphic doesn't mean equal. Each basis of $V$ has a dual basis in $V^*$ but also there is a basis in $V$, dubbed "reciprocal basis", which allows to speak of covariant components a vector in $V$.